# How to store line by line in a variable?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to search for hidden directories or files with "find" and store it in a variable.
I tried like this and it works, but it is stored one after one in TEST.
How can i store it line by line?

```
TEST=$(find /home -name ".*")
echo $TEST
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "line by line"?  Do you want TEST to be an array?

Comment: Or perhaps you just want `echo "$TEST"` which will retain the newlines rather than replacing them with spaces.

Comment: For example: My /home has 3 hidden directories .dir1, .dir2 and .dir3. Now echo $TEST returns .dir1 .dir2 .dir3. But i want it to return .dir1 (newline) .dir2 (newline) .dir3.

Comment: The newlines are in the variable, but the failure to quote the variable causes each line to be treated as a distinct argument to echo, and echo inserts whitespace between the arguments.  Just quote your variable: `echo "$TEST"`

Answer (score 0):

The result of `find` are many lines.

So suggest to read `find` output into array.

```
 readarray -t arr <<< $(find /home -name ".*")
 # print all elements in array arr
 printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
 # print first element in array arr
 echo "${arr[0]}"
 # print second element in array arr
 echo "${arr[2]}"
```